# `search` text only considered the last column in the table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement a `search` functionality in to an `table`. some thing went wrong here, put the search(filter) only considers the last `column` of the table.

any one help me to find out the issue please?

here is the live :

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kdh6m7b3/)

my js:

```
var table = $('table');
$('#search').keyup(function () {
    var tdText = table.find('tbody tr').find('td');
    var text = $.trim($(this).val());
    if(!text){
        table.find('tbody tr').show();
    };
    tdText.filter(function() {
        var reText = $(this).text();

        if (reText.indexOf(text) >= 0) {
            $(this).parent('tr').show();
        }

        else if (reText.indexOf(text) < 0) {
            $(this).parent('tr').hide();
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because when you iterating through each td, you are hiding the `tr` if the text is not matching so when you are iterating the last `td` you are hiding the row if the text is not matched

```
var table = $('table');
$('#search').keyup(function () {
    var tdText = table.find('tbody tr').find('td');
    var text = $.trim($(this).val());
    if(!text){
        table.find('tbody tr').show();
    }else{
        table.find('tbody tr').hide();
        tdText.filter(function() {
            var reText = $(this).text();
            return reText.indexOf(text) >= 0;
        }).parent().show();
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zkv2kLpo/)

---

I think you can simplify it to

```
var table = $('table'), $trs = table.find('tbody tr');
$('#search').keyup(function () {
    var tdText = table.find('tbody tr').find('td');
    var text = $.trim($(this).val());
    if(!text){
        $trs.show();
    }else{
        $trs.hide().has('td:contains('+text+')').show();
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zkv2kLpo/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var tdText = table.find('tbody tr').find('td');
```

Will  find multiple td's. This line loops through the elements and replaces tdText with the next column till last is reached.

Solution is to loop yourself

```js
var tablecells = $('table tbody tr').find('td');
var rowText = "";
$(tablecells).each(function() {
    rowText = rowText + trim($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Object of the original question was not actually to search for content and return that content in the end, but rather to “filter” table rows by displaying only those that have a cell that contains the searched text.

Comment: misunderstood, glad you got your answer though

Answer (score 0):

You are going through *all* `td` of *all* `tr`, but for *each* `td` you show or hide the parent row based on the search result for that `td` – so naturally only the result for the *last* `td` checked is what “survives” in the end for each row.

First of all, you need to split your loop, that goes over *all* `td` of *all* `tr` in one go, into two nested loops – one over the `tr`, and inside that one over all `td` of that row.

And then you should set a flag to determine whether something was found in *any* of the `td` in the row – and then at the end, you show or hide the row based on that flag.

```
var table = $('table');
$('#search').keyup(function () {
    var text = $.trim($(this).val());
    if(!text){
        table.find('tbody tr').show();
    }
    else {
      var rows = table.find('tbody tr');

      rows.each(function() {
         var cells = $(this).find('td'),
             found = false;

         cells.each(function(j, cell) {
            if($(this).text().indexOf(text) >= 0) {
              found = true;
            }
         });

         if(found) {
           $(this).show(); // this is here the row again
         }
         else {
           $(this).hide();
         }    
      });
    }
});
```

Untested – but something along these lines should work.

Notice that I replaced `.filter` by `.each` here – your use of the former made little sense, since you where not actually doing any *filtering* here (that would have required that your callback function returned true or false for each element).